# Google Classrooms API Incorrect Scopes

Tags: c#, google-classroom

New to Oauth 2.0 API's and having some trouble figuring out an isssue with the Google Classrooms API. I utilized the sample code given from Google at the this URL https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/dotnet
and was able to successfully connect to the API and pull down some courses information.

I am now trying to access Classroom Announcements by using the suggested requirements from google https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/list. I modified the code as follows but recieving error message stating  Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]. In the below code, you can see that I have implemented the correct scopes

```
    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Dim Scopes2 As String() = {ClassroomService.Scope.ClassroomAnnouncements, ClassroomService.Scope.ClassroomAnnouncementsReadonly}
    Using stream = New FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim credPath As String = "token.json"
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes2, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " & credPath)
    End Using

    Dim service = New ClassroomService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
        .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        .ApplicationName = ApplicationName
    })

    Dim request As CoursesResource.AnnouncementsResource.ListRequest = service.Courses.Announcements.List("70506149429")
    Dim response As ListAnnouncementsResponse = request.Execute()


    Console.WriteLine("CourseAnnouncements:")

    If response.Announcements IsNot Nothing AndAlso response.Announcements.Count > 0 Then

        For Each announcement In response.Announcements
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", announcement.Text, announcement.Id)
        Next
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No announcement found.")
    End If

    Console.Read()
```

Comment: I ended up figuring out that my tool creates a folder called "token.json" Where I labeled the above credPath as String = "token.json". if I rename or delete this folder it askes me to re-authenticate and allows the connection in.

Comment: It's good you could find the solution to your problem. Please consider post your comment as an answer because not too many people read the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that my tool creates a folder called "token.json" Where I labeled the above credPath as String = "token.json". if I rename or delete this folder it asks me to re-authenticate and allows the connection in.